# How can I access my laptop via .local without having to log in?

Tags: networking, 18.04, avahi

I noticed that my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop is visible to network via `name.local` only after I have logged in.

How can I make it so that it would be possible to access the laptop like this right after boot?

Edit:

I'm using this old crap Ubuntu-laptop as a Jenkins build server. I have to keep my user logged in (GUI) or otherwise the laptop doesn't respond with `name.local` like described above.

Comment: How/why do you want to access your laptop? Via GUI or text terminal? You could probably install/configure a SSH server.

Comment: The network  connection you are using has to be marked 'available to all users' if you want the pc to connect to the network before a user logs in. It seems this is the default for wired connections but not always for wifi ones.

Comment: @Organic Marble Seemed to work. Could you convert that as the answer? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The network connection you are using has to be marked 'All users may connect to this network' if you want the pc to connect to the network before a user logs in. It seems this is the default for wired connections but not always for wifi ones.